# Trigger Javascript for a Server side Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net

I have a situation where i am performing some server action the click of the checkbox and then redirecting the user to another page. But the problem is, After i click the checkbox, it is taking time to redirect as it is slightly slow and hence the users are able to click on other checkboxes. I want to either disable the whole page or disable all the Check boxes. I wrote a javascript but it gets triggered only when the page is loaded again.

**My Html :**

```
   <div> 
    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="checkbox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  CssClass="chk-facet-checkbox"/>

    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox2" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="checkbox2_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  CssClass="chk-facet-checkbox"/>

    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox3" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="checkbox3_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  CssClass="chk-facet-checkbox"/>
    </div>

<div id='blockerdiv'>

</div>
```

**My Jquery :**

```
    if ($(".chk-facet-checkbox").is(":checked")) {
      $('.blockerdiv').show();
//Code to show the 'blockerdiv' as an overlay blocking the whole page
// All we need to do is show the blockerdiv. There is already Code to take care of the overlay
  }
```

Comment: It would be an overlay blocking the whole page if it's defined that way in the style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
$(".chk-facet-checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
```

and so:

```
if ($(".chk-facet-checkbox").is(":checked")) {
      $('.blockerdiv').show();
//Code to show the 'blockerdiv' as an overlay blocking the whole page
// All we need to do is show the blockerdiv. There is already Code to take care of the overlay
     $(".chk-facet-checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
  }
```

This disables all checkbox inputs with that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use   **jquery.blockui.js**

Then simply use **$.blockUI** and **$.unblockUI** functions to block and unblock the UI according to your need.